# my blogs on production not working the way it is in development

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working on rails and trying to make a simple blog site and its working the way i want to on my local machine but when pushed to production its being blocked by the callback functions.
My `before_action :authorized_user?` callback is being called and it prompts for logging if not logged in for performing any method on the blog , and if logged in all methods create, update and destroy methods are working perfectly in my development environment but in production even after the user is logged in also and when the create method is being called it asks for to log in . I am unable to understand from where or what code is causing this to happen because the same is working perfectly fine on local machine.
Any help will he highly appreciated.

My `blog_controller.rb` file is

```rb
class BlogsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_blog, only: [:show, :update, :destroy, :lock_blog, :pin_blog]
  before_action :authorized_user?, except: [:index, :show]

  def index
    
    @blogs = Blog.all
    render json: { blogs: @blogs },status: :ok

  end

  def show
    comments = @blog.comments.select("comments.*, users.username").joins(:user).by_created_at
    render status: :ok, json: { blog: @blog, blog_creator: @blog.user, comments: comments }
  end

  def create

    @blog = Blog.new(blog_params.merge(user_id: @current_user.id))
    
    if authorized?
      if @blog.save
        render status: :ok,
              json: {blog: @blog , notice: "Blog Successfully created"}
      else
        errors = @blog.errors.full_messages.to_sentence
        render status: :unprocessable_entity, json: {error:errors}
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    if authorized?
      if @blog.update(blog_params)
        render status: :ok, 
                  json: {blog: @blog, notice:"Blog successfully updated"}
      else
        render status: :unprocessable_entity,
            json: {errors: @blog.errors.full_messages.to_sentence}
      end 
    else
      handle_unauthorized
    end 
  end

  def destroy 

    if authorized?
      if @blog.destroy
        render status: :ok, 
          json: {notice:'Blog deleted'}
      else
        render status: :unprocessable_entity,
          json: {errors: @blog.errors.full_messages.to_sentence}
      end 
    else
      handle_unauthorized
    end    
  end


  private 

  def set_blog
    @blog = Blog.find(params[:id])
  end

  def blog_params
    params.require(:blog).permit(:title,:body,:image,:is_pinned, :is_locked)
  end

  def authorized?
     @blog.user_id == @current_user.id || @current_user.admin_level >= 1
  end

  def handle_unauthorized
    unless authorized?
      render json:{notice:"Not authorized to perform this task"}, status:401
    end
  end
  
end
```

and `application_controller.rb` file is

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token
    include CurrentUserConcern
    include ExceptionHandlerConcern
    include TokenGenerator


    def authorized_user?
        render json: { notice: 'Please log in to continue' }, status: :unauthorized unless @current_user
    end

    def authorized_admin?
        authorized_user?
        render json: {errors: 'Insufficient Administrative Rights'}, status: 401
    end

    private

end
```

`current_user_concern.rb` file

```
module CurrentUserConcern
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    included do
        before_action :set_current_user
    end

    def set_current_user
        if session[:token]
            @current_user = User.find_by(token: session[:token])
        end
    end

end
```

Comment: Generally, environment-specific issues are caused by not running migrations or installing gems.

Comment: i have checked for .env variables and run rails db:migrate on production to check if those are causing the issues but that isnt the problem

Answer (score 0):

Its generally recommended to use [libraries for authentication](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_authentication) and authorization instead of reinventing the wheel unless its for learning purposes. They have many eyes looking for bugs and insecurites and are battle hardened by tons of users. Home-rolled authentication systems are a very common source of security breaches which could lead to very expensive consequences.

If you're going to roll your own authorization and authentication solution I would suggest you take a page from the libraries like Devise, Pundit and CanCanCan and raise an error when a user is not authorized or authenticated so that you immediately halt whatever the controller is doing and stop the callback chain from executing further.

```
# app/errors/authentication_error.rb
class AuthenticationError < StandardError; end
```

```
# app/errors/authorization_error.rb
class AuthorizationError < StandardError; end
```

```
# app/controllers/concerns/
module Authenticable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    helper_method :current_user, :user_signed_in?
    before_action :authenticate_user
    rescue_from AuthenticationError, with: :handle_unauthorized
  end

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= find_user_from_token if session[:token].present?
  end

  def find_user_from_token
    User.find_by(token: session[:token]) 
  end

  def user_signed_in?
    current_user.present?
  end

  def authenticate_user
    raise AuthenticationError.new('Please log in to continue') unless user_signed_in?
  end

  def handle_unauthenticated(error)
    render json: { 
      notice: error.message
    }, 
    status: :unauthorized
  end
  end
end
```

```
# app/controllers/concerns/authorizable.rb
module Authorizable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    rescue_from AuthenticationError, with: :handle_unauthorized
  end

  def authorize_admin
    raise UserAuthenticationError.new('Insufficient Administrative Rights') unless current_user.admin?
  end

  def handle_unauthorized(error)
    render json:{
      notice: error.message
    }, status: :unauthorized
  end
end
```

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token
  include Authenticable
  include Authorizable
  # Should you really be mixing this into the controller? Seperate the responsibilites!
  include TokenGenerator 
end
```

It also makes debugging much easier as you can disable `rescue_from` in testing so that you get an exception instead of just a cryptic failure message.

You should also setup your authorization system so that it always authenticates (and authorizes) unless you explicitly opt out. This is a best practice that reduces the possible of security breaches simply due to programmer omission. You opt out by calling `skip_before_action :authorize_user`.

Instead of your `set_current_user` use a memoized getter method (`current_user`) to remove issues caused by the ordering of callbacks.  `||=` is conditional assignment and will prevent it from querying the database again if you have already fetched the user. This should be the ONLY method in the system that knows how the user is stored. Do not access `@current_user` directly to avoid leaking the implementation details into the rest of the application.

Methods ending with `?` are by convention [predicate methods in Ruby](https://github.com/rubocop/ruby-style-guide#bool-methods-qmark) and should be expected to return a boolean. Name your modules by what their responsibility is and not what code they contain - avoid the postfix `Concern` as it tells you nothing about what it does.

Comment: Note that when you create new directories (`app/errors`) the autoloader sometimes does pick up on them right away and you sometimes have to call `$ spring stop` and restart the rails server to get it "unstuck".